# Building an IP sacanner in Python that returns a list of active hosts. Only returning one host

Tags: python, list, sockets

I've only been Python-ing for a month and this is the first issue I've not been able to find an answer for!

I'm building a Python script that has an IP scanner as part of its functionality. It looks for hosts on the local network segment with an open Telnet port (23) and returns a list of hosts that it's found. This script is to be run on Windows. Code below:

```
import socket

def isOpen(hostname, port):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(0.1)
    result = sock.connect_ex((hostname, port))
    sock.close()
    return result == 0

def ipScan(start, end):
    livehosts = []
    for i in range (start, end):
        res = isOpen("192.168.1."+str(i), 23)
        if res:
            foundhost = "192.168.1." + str(i)
            livehosts.append(foundhost)
            return livehosts

print (ipScan(0, 254))
```

I know, it's crude and doesn't account for which subnet the scanning computer is in but I've stripped it back to try and troubleshoot.

The problem I'm having is that I'm only being returned a single-item list.

```
['192.168.1.2']
```

There should be 5 devices on the network with open Telnet ports but I can only get this script to return a single device. Desired output is:

```
['192.168.1.2','192.168.1.3','192.168.1.4','192.168.101','192.168.1.124', etc...]
```

Starting the search at a known-active host will return that host but nothing else. E.g. if I start the search at 192.168.1.101 then it will return

```
['192.168.1.101']
```

and not

```
['192.168.1.101', '192.168.1.124', etc...]
```

as it should.

In future I intend to implement threading to imporove performance, and a means of the script discovering which subnet it's in and from that working out what to scan.

Comment: check the indentation of your return statement. It should be outside the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning your list as soon as you find a host that answers:

```
    if res:
        foundhost = "192.168.1." + str(i)
        livehosts.append(foundhost)
        return livehosts   <--
```

Instead, you want the loop to complete before returning:

```
for i in range (start, end):
    res = isOpen("192.168.1."+str(i), 23)
    if res:
        foundhost = "192.168.1." + str(i)
        livehosts.append(foundhost)

return livehosts
```

That way your list can be populated completely before being returned.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! Indentation error, as is often the case.

Comment: @pspkiller91 if this helped you, dont forget to tick the answer so that the question is closed